# Data In Data Out Android App - NullPointerException - Need to implement intent.getLongExtra()

Tags: java, android, eclipse, nullpointerexception

I'm building a simple data in data out type application and I'm getting a FATAL EXCEPTION NullPointerException. I've looked the source up and down and don't see any problems with it. Can someone explain what I might be overlooking? I know it has to do with one of my strings/variables - but I can't seem to pinpoint the exact issue.

LOGCAT:

```
03-29 20:02:37.047: D/OpenGLRenderer(13437): Enabling debug mode 0
03-29 20:02:38.957: D/AndroidRuntime(13437): Shutting down VM
03-29 20:02:38.957: W/dalvikvm(13437): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41f7b930)
03-29 20:02:38.967: E/AndroidRuntime(13437): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-29 20:02:38.967: E/AndroidRuntime(13437): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nfc.linkingmanager/com.nfc.linkingmanager.ViewCountry}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-29 20:02:38.967: E/AndroidRuntime(13437):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
03-29 20:02:38.967: E/AndroidRuntime(13437):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
03-29 20:02:38.967: E/AndroidRuntime(13437):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-29 20:02:38.967: E/AndroidRuntime(13437):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
03-29 20:02:38.967: E/AndroidRuntime(13437):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-29 20:02:38.967: E/AndroidRuntime(13437):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-29 20:02:38.967: E/AndroidRuntime(13437):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-29 20:02:38.967: E/AndroidRuntime(13437):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-29 20:02:38.967: E/AndroidRuntime(13437):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-29 20:02:38.967: E/AndroidRuntime(13437):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-29 20:02:38.967: E/AndroidRuntime(13437):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-29 20:02:38.967: E/AndroidRuntime(13437):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-29 20:02:38.967: E/AndroidRuntime(13437): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-29 20:02:38.967: E/AndroidRuntime(13437):    at com.nfc.linkingmanager.ViewCountry.onCreate(ViewCountry.java:32)
03-29 20:02:38.967: E/AndroidRuntime(13437):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
03-29 20:02:38.967: E/AndroidRuntime(13437):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
03-29 20:02:38.967: E/AndroidRuntime(13437):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
03-29 20:02:38.967: E/AndroidRuntime(13437):    ... 11 more
```

JAVA:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class ViewCountry extends Activity {

       private long rowID;
       private TextView nameTv;
       private TextView capTv;
       private TextView codeTv; 
       private TextView timeTv; 

       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
       {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.view_country);

          setUpViews();
          Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
          rowID = extras.getLong(CountryList.ROW_ID); 
       }

       private void setUpViews() {
           nameTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameText);
           capTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.capText);
           timeTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeEdit);
           codeTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.codeText);
       }

       @Override
       protected void onResume()
       {
          super.onResume();
          new LoadContacts().execute(rowID);
       } 

       private class LoadContacts extends AsyncTask<Long, Object, Cursor> 
       {
          DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(ViewCountry.this);

          @Override
          protected Cursor doInBackground(Long... params)
          {
             dbConnector.open();
             return dbConnector.getOneContact(params[0]);
          } 

          @Override
          protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result)
          {
             super.onPostExecute(result);

             result.moveToFirst();
             // get the column index for each data item
             int nameIndex = result.getColumnIndex("name");
             int capIndex = result.getColumnIndex("cap");
             int codeIndex = result.getColumnIndex("code");
             int timeIndex = result.getColumnIndex("time");

             nameTv.setText(result.getString(nameIndex));
             capTv.setText(result.getString(capIndex));
//           timeTv.setText(result.getInt(timeIndex)); // <--- HERE WAS AN ERROR
             timeTv.setText(result.getString(timeIndex)); // time was stored as Sting all the time
             codeTv.setText(result.getString(codeIndex));

             result.close();
             dbConnector.close();
          }
       } 


       @Override
       public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
       {
          super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
          MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
          inflater.inflate(R.menu.view_country_menu, menu);
          return true;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
       {
          switch (item.getItemId())
          {
             case R.id.editItem:
                Intent addEditContact =
                   new Intent(this, AddEditCountry.class);

                addEditContact.putExtra(CountryList.ROW_ID, rowID);
                addEditContact.putExtra("name", nameTv.getText());
                addEditContact.putExtra("cap", capTv.getText());
                addEditContact.putExtra("code", codeTv.getText());
                startActivity(addEditContact); 
                return true;

             case R.id.deleteItem:
                deleteContact();
                return true;

             default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
          } 
       }

       private void deleteContact()
       {

          AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(ViewCountry.this);

          alert.setTitle(R.string.confirmTitle); 
          alert.setMessage(R.string.confirmMessage); 

          alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.delete_btn,
             new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
             {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int button)
                {
                   final DatabaseConnector dbConnector = 
                      new DatabaseConnector(ViewCountry.this);

                   AsyncTask<Long, Object, Object> deleteTask =
                      new AsyncTask<Long, Object, Object>()
                      {
                         @Override
                         protected Object doInBackground(Long... params)
                         {
                            dbConnector.deleteContact(params[0]); 
                            return null;
                         } 

                         @Override
                         protected void onPostExecute(Object result)
                         {
                            finish(); 
                         }
                      };

                   deleteTask.execute(new Long[] { rowID });               
                }
             }
          );

          alert.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel_btn, null).show();
       }
    }
```

Comment: You should learn how to find out where the error is. In the logcat window double click on the line at com.nfc.linkingmanager.ViewCountry.onCreate(ViewCountry.java:32)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A NullPointerException is being thrown in your `onCreate()` method. I suspect `getIntent().getExtras()` is returning null, so your call to `extras.getLong()` is throwing the exception.

Comment: Excellent to know! How can I resolve this issue? (I'm new to android development)

Comment: I have a feeling I should enable a breakpoint (judging from what I've read - but I'm not sure what im looking for)

Comment: Do a null check on extras: `if (extras != null) { ... }`. Or, use `intent.getLongExtra()`, which will automatically give you back the default value you provided if the intent extras are null. NullPointerException is a Java thing, really. It means you are trying to call something on an object that is null.

Comment: Extras and SavedInstance State are returning null

Comment: How can I fix this? (I really appreciate your assistance!)

Comment: As i said, using `intent.getLongExtra(String key, long defaultValue)` will simply return the defaultValue you provided if there are no extras bundled with the intent. It is ok for savedInstanceState to be null since you are not calling a method on it (or accessing a member variable) with the `.` operator.